# Page Build Failed due to the plugin jekyll-scholar

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

Build is successful locally and the `jekyll serve` brings the page locally. But when I push the files into github pages repository, I receive an email saying that the page build failed.

Visited the documentation and it was mentioned that the build may fail due to any unsupported plugin. In my config.yml file, I had this plugin: ['jekyll/scholar']. 
Any help is appreciated to fix this build issue !

Comment: A repository url can help.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages has a whitelist of plugins that it allows. It appears that the plugin you list isn't in the whitelist, so you can't use it on your GitHub Pages site.

See this documentation for how to find out what's in the list. (Note that the "How to bypass the whitelist" section only applies to local builds.)

https://github.com/github/pages-gem